# How to run Pytorch on Macbook pro (M1) GPU?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, apple-m1

I tried to train a model using PyTorch on my Macbook pro. It uses the new generation apple M1 CPU. However, PyTorch couldn't recognize my GPUs.

```
GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
```

Does anyone know any solution?

I have updated all the libraries to the latest versions.

Comment: There is currently [no way](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47702) to do that.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit that added a solution, as questions are not meant to be updated with answers. You should go ahead and post an answer instead. You can copy the text that you used directly from the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c1a0d84d-c54e-44d7-8991-2870ebc5083c/view-source).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PyTorch added support for M1 GPU as of 2022-05-18 in the Nightly version. Read more about it in their [blog post](https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/).

<s>Simply install nightly:
`conda install pytorch -c pytorch-nightly --force-reinstall`</s>

**Update:** It's available in the stable version:

- Conda:`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch`
- pip: `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio`

To use ([source](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/mps.html)):

```
mps_device = torch.device("mps")

# Create a Tensor directly on the mps device
x = torch.ones(5, device=mps_device)
# Or
x = torch.ones(5, device="mps")

# Any operation happens on the GPU
y = x * 2

# Move your model to mps just like any other device
model = YourFavoriteNet()
model.to(mps_device)

# Now every call runs on the GPU
pred = model(x)
```

Comment: If you don't want to use Conda for this, you can check out my [boilerplate repo](https://github.com/alexfromapex/tensorexperiments) where I demonstrate installing it with Poetry

Comment: As of now, the [official docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) lets you use `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch` in order to run on m1 macs as well .

Comment: what about tensorflow.js?

Comment: What is the difference between Conda and Pip?

Answer (score 17):

It looks like PyTorch support for the M1 GPU is in the works, but is not yet complete.

From [@soumith](https://github.com/soumith) on GitHub:

> So, here's an update.
> We plan to get the M1 GPU supported. @albanD, @ezyang and a few core-devs have been looking into it. I can't confirm/deny the involvement of any other folks right now.
>
> So, what we have so far is that we had a prototype that was just about okay. We took the wrong approach (more graph-matching-ish), and the user-experience wasn't great -- some operations were really fast, some were really slow, there wasn't a smooth experience overall. One had to guess-work which of their workflows would be fast.
>
> So, we're completely re-writing it using a new approach, which I think is a lot closer to your good ole PyTorch, but it is going to take some time. I don't think we're going to hit a public alpha in the next ~4 months.
>
> We will open up development of this backend as soon as we can.

That post:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47702#issuecomment-965625139

TL;DR: a public beta is at least 4 months out.

Comment: any update on this? 

Comment: Do we use torch.device("cpu") for now?

Comment: but can we install pytorch for cpu for Apple Silicon? I didn't find that also

Answer (score 8):

For those who couldn't install using `conda` like me use `pip` as following:-

##### Requirement:

- Any Macbook with apple silicon chip
- macOS version 12.3+

##### Installation:

`pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu`

> #### Update:
>
> No need of nightly version. Pytorch version 1.12 now supports GPU acceleration in apple silicon. Simply install using following command:-
>
> `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio`
>
> You may follow other instructions for using pytorch in apple silicon and getting your benchmark.

##### Usage:

Make sure you use `mps` as your device as following:

```
device = torch.device('mps')

# Send you tensor to GPU
my_tensor = my_tensor.to(device)
```

##### Benchmarking (on M1 Max, 10-core CPU, 24-core GPU):

1. Without using GPU

```
import torch
device = torch.device('cpu')
x = torch.rand((10000, 10000), dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.rand((10000, 10000), dtype=torch.float32)
x = x.to(device)
y = y.to(device)
```

```
%%timeit
x * y
```

```
17.9 ms ± 390 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

2. Using GPU **(5x faster)**

```
import torch
device = torch.device('mps')
x = torch.rand((10000, 10000), dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.rand((10000, 10000), dtype=torch.float32)
x = x.to(device)
y = y.to(device)
```

```
%%timeit
x * y
```

```
3.43 ms ± 57.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Using the same Mac and code, I found 'mps' to be slower than 'cpu'. This could be because the calculation is not large enough.