# PyTorch is running natively on M1 MacBook, but something isn't working properly

Tags: pytorch, apple-m1

I've just got an M1 MacBook Pro and have been working on getting my development environment set up. I have followed instructions to install PyTorch with mini-forge so that it will run natively.

To test this, I've been running the MNIST example code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/examples/master/mnist/main.py). The code runs fine and Activity Monitor shows me that it is running natively. However, something still seems to be wrong: when the exact same code is executed on my other machine accuracy of 99% is achieved usually after one epoch, and test loss is very low. On the M1 Macbook, although training loss goes down, test loss never drops below 2 and accuracy never exceeds 10% after 14 epochs.

Similar issues occurred when running other code, e.g. [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/tutorials/master/beginner_source/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.py) produces a loss of nan at every step.

I haven't been able to find this issue mentioned anywhere else: PyTorch is running natively on the M1, but it just doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what might be causing this or how I might fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this using some low-precision arithmetic? That would explain the issues you are seeing. Try this: `for p in my_model.parameters(): print(p.dtype)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Pytorch on Macbook pro (M1) GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820453/how-to-run-pytorch-on-macbook-pro-m1-gpu)