# MacBook m1 pro gpu for training Hugging Face, Transformers, PyTorch

Tags: macos, pytorch, gpu, huggingface-transformers

I was wondering if I can train Hugging Face models with PyTorch on MacBook pro M1 Pro GPU?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of what you have tried so far? Are there any error messages that you encounter?

Comment: Hi @dennlinger I think PyTorch is not supporting GPU for macbook pro

Comment: dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820453/how-to-run-pytorch-on-macbook-pro-m1-gpu

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now it is available!
See:https://sebastianraschka.com/blog/2022/pytorch-m1-gpu.html
Remember to use python env run on arm64.