# RuntimeError: The MPS backend is supported on MacOS 12.3+.Current OS version can be queried using `sw_vers`

Tags: python, pytorch, apple-silicon

Since Pytorch GPU support for apple silicon was just released, I tried to install PyTorch using the steps on the following link. As of now, only a nightly build is available so I installed it. However, when I run the following code, I get the error.

#### Link I followed:

1. https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/
2. https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

#### Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return output


def train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
            if args.dry_run:
                break


def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item()  # sum up batch loss
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))


def main():
    # Training settings
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch MNIST Example')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=64, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for training (default: 64)')
    parser.add_argument('--test-batch-size', type=int, default=1000, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for testing (default: 1000)')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=14, metavar='N',
                        help='number of epochs to train (default: 14)')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=1.0, metavar='LR',
                        help='learning rate (default: 1.0)')
    parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.7, metavar='M',
                        help='Learning rate step gamma (default: 0.7)')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='cpu',
                        help='choose device')
    parser.add_argument('--dry-run', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='quickly check a single pass')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=1, metavar='S',
                        help='random seed (default: 1)')
    parser.add_argument('--log-interval', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
                        help='how many batches to wait before logging training status')
    parser.add_argument('--save-model', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='For Saving the current Model')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

    device = torch.device(args.device)

    train_kwargs = {'batch_size': args.batch_size}
    test_kwargs = {'batch_size': args.test_batch_size}
    #if use_cuda:
    #    cuda_kwargs = {'num_workers': 1,
    #                   'pin_memory': True,
    #                   'shuffle': True}
    #    train_kwargs.update(cuda_kwargs)
    #    test_kwargs.update(cuda_kwargs)

    transform=transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
        ])
    dataset1 = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True,
                       transform=transform)
    dataset2 = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False,
                       transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset1,**train_kwargs)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset2, **test_kwargs)

    model = Net().to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adadelta(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)

    scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=args.gamma)
    for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
        train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
        test(model, device, test_loader)
        scheduler.step()

    if args.save_model:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "mnist_cnn.pt")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # run with --device cpu or --device mps
```

#### Error:

##### RuntimeError: The MPS backend is supported on MacOS 12.3+.Current OS version can be queried using `sw_vers`. I am not sure how to use this argument `sw_vers`.

#### My Macbook specification:

- Model: M1 Max
- OS Version: 12.2.1

From my inspection, it looks like my OS needs to at least 12.3 for it to run however it says I can use `sw_vers` to run it on my current OS. I don't want to update because of other libraries compatibility issue. Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: I got the same issue

Comment: Updating macOS to 12.3 fixed the issue. Make sure you follow installation steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401340/6117565

Answer (score 1):

setting device to 'cpu' works for me

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
```

Comment: Yes cpu would work however it defects the purpose of using GPU in Mac in the first place.